# Tagged questions page leads to broken RSS feed link

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, feed

Searching for tags (ie, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20-android%20-spring%20-hibernate%20-java-ee%20-c%2b%2b%20-c%23 ) leads to a broken RSS link (ie, the RSS link for the aforementioned search as linked from the RSS icon in my Opera address bar is https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/java+-android+-spring+-hibernate+-java-ee+-c%2b%2b+-c%23 ) which may or may not return a 404 depending on which/how many tags are listed in the URL.

How can I get an RSS feed which filters by more than a few tags?

Why does a URL return a 404 depending on the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh.

Looks like the link in the header (meta-data intended for the browser to use for sussing out things like feeds) has the wrong (broken) URL.

```
 <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" 
       title="Feed of questions tagged java -android -spring -hibernate -java-ee -c++ -c#" 
       href="/feeds/tag/java+-android+-spring+-hibernate+-java-ee+-c%2b%2b+-c%23" />
```

Fortunately, the link actually displayed on the page has the right URL:

[image: The feed link, as it appears on the page]

> /feeds/tag?tagnames=java%20-android%20-spring%20-hibernate%20-java-ee%20-c%2b%2b%20-c%23&sort=newest

So... Until this is fixed, use the link on the page instead of the one your browser exposes.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think to check for an alternate.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in `rev 1903` (meta) and `rev 1336` (network).