# Chat RSS feed for tagged/xxx broken

Tags: bug, status-review, chat, search, feed

When you use the `tagged/` prefix for a search term in chat, you (are supposed to) get all messages with a specific tag. <sup>1</sup>

However, the generated RSS link in the lower right corner of the results is broken, and simply produces a 404 error page.

For example, [this search](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=tagged%2Fcv-pls&room=11540) finds [cv-pls](/questions/tagged/cv-pls) posts in the Charcoal HQ room. Down on the lower right of the page, you get this link:

> [[image] tagged/cv-pls](https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/tagged%2fcv-pls)

which currently takes you to the 404 page.

As some kind of workaround, I have found that searching for [the tag in square brackets](https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/%5bcv-pls%5d) appears to work, though I have not explored the corner cases.

---

<sup>1</sup> In actual practice, it looks like you also get results which simply contain the word, not as a tag; but that is not the topic of this post.

Perhaps notice also that when the link works, it takes you to an RSS feed for hits in all rooms, not just the one you searched in, and which the result page displays. I imagine this has been reported as a bug / feature request in the past; again, that is not the topic of this bug report.

As far as I can tell, this is distinct from, albeit perhaps related to, [Tagged questions page leads to broken RSS feed link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121292/tagged-questions-page-leads-to-broken-rss-feed-link)

Comment: Come to think of it, the square brackets might as well be omitted; they too find any chat message which contains this word anywhere.

Comment: I seem to have posted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391102/chat-rss-feed-for-tagged-xxx-not-working a few years prior. Sorry for the apparent self-duplicate. (I can't remember if this was a mistake or a considered action at the time.)